# Bash: can't access history inside functions or scripts

Tags: bash

Imagine this situation:

```
 $ c3
 I'm c3 command. Done.
 $ c4
 I'm c4 command. Everything is alright here.
 $ c5
 I'm c5 command. You have a problem, I give up the task!
 $ history 5
 11 c1
 12 c2
 13 c3
 14 c4
 15 c5
```

We can repeat the command c3 by doing !13, the output is:

```
 $ !13
  c3
     I'm c3 command. Done.
```

I tried to use the `!` operator inside my .bashrc (in a function), but it doesn't work. I also tried to make a shell script to use it without success. Is there a way to do that?

Tries that didn't work:

```
 # inside .bashrc or .bash_functions
 function histtest()
 {
     echo 'history #13'
     ta="you're missing something..."

     # uncomment **one** of these two lines at a time
     ta="!13"
     # ta=!13    

     echo $ta
 }
```

A t.sh file:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 test=!13
 #test="!13"
 #test='!13'     # of course not

 echo "$test"
```

Comment: But what happens if `!13` is not `c3`, but for example `find / -type f -delete` ? And since you are in a script, you can repeat whatever by duplicating the line or creating a function.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Forget about how to expand history in a function like that: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

From the bash(1) man page:

> #### HISTORY EXPANSION
>
> The  shell supports a history expansion feature that is similar to the history expansion in csh. This feature is enabled by default for interactive shells, and can be disabled using the +H option to the set builtin command.  Non-interactive shells do not perform history expansion by default.

I do not recommend enabling history expansion in shell scripts. You could do it with `set -H`, but seriously, don't do it. It really should only be used interactively.

Comment: 1) Can I enable it for a single script? 2) For my single included file in my .bashrc? 3) For my whole .bashrc? (which is not as safe, I agree)

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Can you edit that into your question? I can't think of why you'd need to, even in `.bashrc`.

Comment: I have some troubles with bash's history. One of the problems that bothered me for a few years is that **history -d** only accepts a single number/arg. So I did a function to delete several history numbers at once - simple one. The function checks the order is reverse, so it works as intended (carefully check this, number change naturally). But I wanted to show the lines being deleted to have a last chance of undoing it. This is where it stopped. Should I put these in my question? I don't mind sharing the script, but it isn't that good.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable. I would say erase your existing question and replace it with that comment. Or post your comment as a new question. Your question should really be about how to print history entries in a script, rather than how to get history *expansions* to work.